# LXD external static ip

Tags: virtualization, linux-networking, lxc, lxd

I'm using LXD for managing LXC containers. I used the "standard" bridged NAT setup up to now. But know I got an additional static ip which is external available. I want to attach it to my container but cant get it working within the LXD network config.
Moreover I have a /64 IPv6 network on my host, where I also want one adress being assigned to my container.

Can anyone provide some configuration hints?